# Rails problems posting to users_controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an action in my users_controller that removes a user's picture.

```
  def use_fb_photo
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.picture? and @user.uid
      @user.remove_picture!
      if @user.save
        redirect_to :back
      end
    end
  end
```

routes.rb

```
post 'users/:id/use_fb_photo', to: 'users#use_fb_photo', as: :use_fb_photo
```

I figured I would need to send the user id to this action using a form.

```
   <%= form_for @user, url: use_fb_photo_path, html: {id: "use-fb-photo-form", class: nil} do |f| %>
    <% end %>
```

I want the user to trigger the action by clicking a button that is already inside a different form.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default fb-photo" title="Use facebook photo"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

and the js

```
 $('.fb-photo').on('click', function () {
    $('#use-fb-photo-form').submit();
  });
```

I am getting the error `No route matches [PATCH] "/users/17/use_fb_photo"`.

If I change routes to patch ... instead of post I get a template missing error.
I feel like I am making this too complicated but my brain is fried from coding all day.

I just want the user to click a button (that has to be inside another form) which removes the user's picture and redirects to their profile page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`form_for` by default send `PATCH`, but your route waits `POST`. You can add `method: 'post'` to your `form_for` or change route to `PATCH`

Comment: Ok, that helped with the no route matches error, but now it's asking for a template

Comment: I think it's because my redirect was inside the if statement

Comment: In your action, your code is't health. if-else should be together.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss

```
method: :delete
```

in the call.

Comment: I don't think that's right.  I'm not deleting a record, I'm just making a change to it.  I am posting params (user id) to the controller action.

Comment: And picture is the parameter of user or is it the user has_many pictures? I am overcoded too, so maybe I just ask crapy questions.

Comment: it is a parameter of the user